# PhoneGap with Openlayers: popup which to redirect to another page get a error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, openlayers

I have a PhoneGap application use Openlayers to show local map. I use a popup to show information of location which appeared before by a marker. I append a link into this popup to redirect to another page, but i get a error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" when click popup to redirect. New pages still show but don't have any js library or css are loaded, so generating error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". I think all js libraries are no longer in the DOM when redirect from popup.
I use Ajax to load other pages and add it to DOM, so I reference all js libraries in a first page is index.html. I redirect successful with other redirections in my application.

Comment: post the code of where you get this error.

Comment: Omar, I was posted my code, any idea?

Comment: Try removing `data-dom-cache`.

Comment: Thanks Omar, but i still get this error. Any idea?

Comment: Why do you use `preventDefault()`? also, the error appears in location-Detail.html? or do you have other JS code somewhere else?

Comment: Omar, this error appears at line "$(document).ready(function(){" in location-Detail.html with description is "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", I put all custom js libraries in index.html(home). I also have location.html to show list of locations, when I click on a location will redirect to location-Detail.html, it worked fine. Please help me with your idea!

Comment: I don't understand why DOM missing all js libraries and css with only this case.

Comment: Remove `$(document).ready`..etc, keep `pageshow`.

Comment: I don't think so, i removed $(document).ready, but i get error at next line is "$('#locationDetail').die().live("pageshow", function( event ) {" with the same error. I think jquery.js was missing in DOM.

Comment: ok replace `die().live()` by `.on('pageshow')..etc`

Comment: the problem is in `die()` remove it or use `.off` instead check this http://api.jquery.com/die/

Comment: I have replaced the above, but it's not solution. The problem is compiler don't know "$" because the jquery.js was missing. If I append this tag <a> with href="locationDetail.html?..." into <li> in listview, it work fine. Else, i append this tag into popup of Openlayers then get error as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code and our conversation, links generated outside JQM, won't be recognized by it. Thus, it essential to link jQuery and jQuery Mobile to the new link.

In your code, a link was generated by OpenLayer and not by JQM.